# Can not validate the radio button field using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if the radio button input field is checked or not using Javascript/Jquery. Actually I am setting the radio button field dynamically but while checking whether this field is checked or not it's showing me the result false where it is really checked. My code is below.

```
<input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" onClick="selectScale(this.value,'0');" value="<?php echo $v['_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $v['answertype'];  ?>
```

My javascript code is below.

```
$('#answer_type0[value="' + qdata[0].answer_type + '"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');    
console.log('check',document.getElementById('answer_type0').checked);
```

Here my radio input field seems checked on the UI page but while i am checking the `console.log` message its showing false. Here I need if the radio button field is checked it should give the message true but it's not happening like that.

Comment: Please include the *rendered* html, not just the php version.

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle.net showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking like this.

```
if($('#answer_type0').is(':checked')){
   console.log("true");
}else{
   console.log("false");
}
```

Comment: Actually my problem is the radio button is checked but its showing false.

Comment: Did you try using my answer to check if it is false?

Comment: I did it like this `console.log('check',$('#answer_type0').is(':checked'));` but its giving the result false but actually the radio button is checked.

Comment: I did as per you and got the result what i have explained above.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it by the following methods

```
 if ($("#answer_type0").prop("checked")) {
          alert("checked");
        }
      else
      {
      alert ("not checked");
      }

        // OR
        if ($("#answer_type0").is(":checked")) {
           alert("checked");
        }
       else
       {
       alert ("not checked");
       }
```

Comment: Its not the solution.Here my radio button field is checked but its showing as false.

Comment: then the problem is with the $('#answer_type0[value="' + qdata[0].answer_type + '"]') check whether the check box value is same as in html that's why it returns false

Comment: So whats the solution for this.