# Can not check the radio button using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need one help.I need to check the radio button and set its value using Javascipt/Jquery.I am explaining my code below.

```
<input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" value="" onClick="selectScale();">Male
    <button type="button" id="btn">Edit</button>
    <script >
        document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){
            var qdata='123';
            $('#answer_type0[value="' + qdata + '"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
            //$('#answer_type0').prop("checked",true);
            console.log('checked',$("#answer_type0").prop("checked"));
        }
        function selectScale(){
            console.log('value');
        }
    </script>
```

On the above code when user will click on `Edit` button the radio button should check and the `click` should trigger. But in my case its not happening like this. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rMp4qdD5azXyG6xOyi1L?p=preview) the plunkr is present.Please help me.

Comment: Can you make this correct ?

Comment: In the selector you're expecting the input to have a value attribute which it doesn't.

Comment: check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ya8z86s7/)

Comment: i have tried also what you have done.i need to set its value also while clicked. in this case its not coming.

Comment: 4 hours ago there was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38408584/can-not-validate-the-radio-button-field-using-javascript-jquery) exact same question

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer

```
<input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" value="" onClick="selectScale();">Male
<button type="button" id="btn">Edit</button>
<script>
  document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    var qdata = '0';
    $('[name=answer_type' + qdata + ']').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');
    console.log('checked', $("#answer_type0").prop("checked"));
  }

  function selectScale() {
    var qdata = '0';
    $('[name=answer_type' + qdata + ']').val('some_value');
    console.log('some_value');
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Please test inside my plunkr.

Comment: Not working? Can you explain what not working? Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qLyx07ch/

Comment: Ok,But i need to set also its value dynamically.

Comment: Tell me where you want to set value? Explain more

Comment: check this line ` $('#answer_type0[value="' + qdata + '"]').prop('checked', true).trigger('click');` from my code.

Comment: you can check [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rMp4qdD5azXyG6xOyi1L?p=preview) also.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="radio" name="answer_type0" id="answer_type0" value="" onClick="selectScale();">Male
    <button type="button" id="btn">Edit</button>
    <script >
        $(document).ready(function(){
          document.getElementById('btn').onclick=function(){

            $('#answer_type0').prop("checked",true);
        }
        function selectScale(){
            console.log('value');
        }
       });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```